# Variable inside python format specifier

Tags: python, format

I am wondering whether I can add a variable inside the f string to specify the width of item to be printed.
For example:

```
print("{:>5}".format("cat"))
```

In the example how can I replace 5 with a variable that can change at runtime.

Comment: `pad = 5; print("{:>{x}}".format("cat", x = pad))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
a = 5
print("{:>"f"{a}""}".format("cat"))
```

Output:

```
  cat
```

---

---

---

You can also do that using `str.rjust()`:

```
a = 5
print("cat".rjust(a))
```

Output:

```
  cat
```

Answer (score 1):

> inside the f string

Be careful using the term "f string" -- you're talking about a *format string* whereas an *f-string* is a feature of the latest releases of Python and something different, but related:

```
animal = 'cat'
pad = 5

print(f"{animal:>{pad}}")
```

Otherwise, if you just want a *format string* without the *f-string*, then @JohnnyMopp's comment (+1) shows the correct syntax.